# How to purge "(deleted) files" in /tmp - Debian

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze

On Debian 6, I have these big files which are linked to python

```
/tmp/tmpLwS5ny.tbuf (deleted)
/tmp/tmpMjH6hy.tbuf (deleted)
/tmp/tmpGtY5dz.tbuf (deleted)
```

I don't want to reboot the server, but should I delete them?
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this script as a cron job to remove the files without rebooting

```
#!/bin/sh
# Clean file and dirs more than 3 days old in /tmp nightly

/usr/bin/find /tmp -type f -atime +2 -mtime +2  |xargs  /bin/rm -f &&

/usr/bin/find /tmp -type d -mtime +2 -exec /bin/rm -rf '{}' \; &&

/usr/bin/find /tmp -type l -ctime +2 |xargs /bin/rm -f &&

/usr/bin/find -L /tmp -mtime +2 -print -exec rm -f {} \;
```

save the contents above to a file chmod 775 the file and create a cron entry to run it

Comment: I try it by putting it in a nightly sh file.